# Split SparkR dataframe into list of dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am new to sparkR and trying to split the sparkR dataframe in to list of Dataframes based on columns.

The data has a billion records of `Sls_D(date), mdse_item_i(item id), co_loc_i(location id), traffic_ti_8_00, traffic_ti_9_00, traffic_ti_10_00, traffic_ti_11_00` (each has no of traffic in the specific hour).

Data Snapshot:

```
sls_d co_loc_i   mdse_item_i traffic_ti_8_00 traffic_ti_9_00 traffic_ti_10_00 traffic_ti_11_00

    1 2016-10-21     1592     4694620               1             113              156              209
    2 2016-10-21     1273     4694620               1              64              152              249
    3 2016-10-21     1273    15281024               1              64              152              249
    4 2016-10-21     1498     4694620               2              54              124              184
    5 2016-10-21     1498    15281024               2              54              124              184
```

Desired Output:

```
 sls_d         co_loc_i  mdse_item_i  traffic_ti_8_00  traffic_ti_9_00 traffic_ti_10_00 traffic_ti_11_00 
 2016-10-21        4     4694620               3              67              145              283
```

A list of Dataframes.

```
d.2 = split(data.2.2,list(data.2.2$mdse_item_i,data.2.2$co_loc_i,data.2.2$sls_d))
```

> Error in x[ind[[k]]] :    Expressions other than filtering predicates
>   are not supported in the first parameter of extract operator [ or
>   subset() method.

Is there any way around to do this in sparkR apart from converting the sparkDataframe to base R.
As converting the sparkdataframe to base R results in memory error and defeats the problem of parallel processing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear; if you mean to split the columns of a *Spark* dataframe, you should use [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/select.html). Here is an example using the `iris` data in SparkR 2.2:

```r
df <- as.DataFrame(iris)  # Spark dataframe
df
# SparkDataFrame[Sepal_Length:double, Sepal_Width:double, Petal_Length:double, Petal_Width:double, Species:string]

# separate the length-related & width-related columns into 2 Spark dataframes:
df_length = select(df, 'Sepal_Length', 'Petal_Length')
df_width = select(df, 'Sepal_Width', 'Petal_Width')

head(collect(df_width)) # for demonstration purposes only
#   Sepal_Width Petal_Width
# 1         3.5         0.2
# 2         3.0         0.2
# 3         3.2         0.2
# 4         3.1         0.2
# 5         3.6         0.2
# 6         3.9         0.4
```

Now, you can put these 2 *Spark* dataframes into an *R* list, <s>but I'm not sure how useful this will be - any list operations that may make sense are not usable</s> [EDIT after comment]:

```r
my_list = c(df_length, df_width)
head(collect(my_list[[1]]))
#   Sepal_Length Petal_Length
# 1          5.1          1.4
# 2          4.9          1.4
# 3          4.7          1.3
# 4          4.6          1.5
# 5          5.0          1.4
# 6          5.4          1.7
```